# I want my vb.net program with sqldb to be transferable

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, sql-server-2005, connection, connection-string

I'm having trouble with my vb.net program. It has a database with a `SqlConnection` string of:

```
DbConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=ACE-DUO;Initial Catalog=db_CVSO;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pwd")
```

I made an installer for this vb.net program but I'm having problems regarding my SQL Server connection string. It's because once I installed the program in different computer. The server name in my case (ACE-DUO) changes and the database itself cannot be located.

I know how to detach the file and attach it to vb.net program. what I'm really aiming for is that I want the connection string to change on based where the program resources were placed.

For example, if the program was installed in the `C:\Program Files\MyDatabase` folder, I want to make it as a part of the connection string so it would be opened in different computer.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: `Application.ExecutablePath` will give you the location of the executable that started the application. You could remove the executable name from this and concantinate it into your Conection String.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Comment: @Pezzzz the problem is the server name not where or how to attach the file name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to specify connectionstring of sql server while installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846327/how-to-specify-connectionstring-of-sql-server-while-installation)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need multiple shared access to your database you could take advandage of the LocalDB feature of Sql Server 2012.
You connection string could be changed to

```
 DbConn = New SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated " & _ 
                            "Security=true;AttachDbFileName=C:\Program Files\MyDatabase\db.mdf;"
```

[Article on LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx)

Comment: I tried that one using this: DbConn = New SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\db_CVSO.mdf;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pwd;")



but I currently got this error. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException(0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server.



I'm trying if I can figure this out myself. I'm new in this area so I'm sorry If I can't follow up too well.

Comment: I tried putting the database (mdf file) in the C:\ I want trying to access it from that location.

Comment: @chloe: `LocalDB` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** - it won't work with the 2005 version...

Comment: Start removing the User ID and the password, use the Integrated Security=true. Usually, the root folder of disk C:  lacks the read/write permissions. Try in another place like c:\database and be sure to have the read/write permissions

Comment: @marc_s right, I have seen the comment now. The OP need to install the LocalDB bits [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062). At this point I am not sure if all this work really worths

Comment: thanks for answering me, but how can I allow read/write permissions in that location?

Comment: I think that this job is reserved for your install utility.

Comment: I changed the Connection into : "Server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Database\db_CVSO.mdf;Integrated Security=True;" but i still have the same error.

Comment: I'm currently downloading the SqlLocaLDB from the site you've given. I'll try if it will work after it's installation but do you know any other way to solve my problem? sorry for the bother and thanks