# Change the Data source based on user of the program

Tags: database, vb.net, t-sql, installation, connection-string

The "Data Source" in the sql connection is based on what the user specified during installation right? What I want is to change the data source which is in my case "ACE-DUO" into a different source. For example, upon deployment of my program the server name of the new user is "Jill" i want my data source to change like:

From:

DbConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=ACE-DUO;AttachDbFilename=C:\Database\db_CVSO.mdf;Integrated Security=True")

Into

DbConn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=Jill;AttachDbFilename=C:\Database\db_CVSO.mdf;Integrated Security=True")

thanks for the answers in advance. I'm still new to sql so I'm sorry if you find this question stupid. I'm trying to make an installer for my vb.net program but I have that problem for my connection string when i install the program in my friend's computer. I want the connection string to change during run time based on what I have said earlier.

I used the publish for the installer. I also don't know yet how to create a basic installer for my vb.net application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to specify connectionstring of sql server while installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846327/how-to-specify-connectionstring-of-sql-server-while-installation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server is always the same computer the program is deployed on, you could use Data Source=localhost.

Otherwise, you could have a prompt for the server name when the program is first run after deployment, and save it in User Settings. From then on, when your program starts, it can get the server name from the user settings, and use that in the connection string.