# Deploying Winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment

I'm having trouble creating an installation program for my Winforms application.  I am using the Windows Installer and the publish function.  It creates a nice setup program.  After I run the setup on a client machine, I want to update the App.config file to point to a different database than was used for the setup.  I have this setting in the app.config file.  However, I am not able to update the app.config file on the client's machine.  Temporarily, I am creating a new build when I want to change the database that the application points to.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate of...

[Setup App.Config As Custom Action in Setup Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249159/setup-app-config-as-custom-action-in-setup-project)

?

The answer looks good...

http://raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/